# Best way to import multiple MaterialUI components under common namespace without importing the whole library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, material-ui

I want my MaterialUI components to exist under the same namespace to avoid mixing names with other libraries (e.g. so that it's clear that `<Box>` means `<MaterialUI.Box>` and not `<SomeOtherLibrary>.Box>`.
Logically this seems like a simple thing to do, but for the life of me I can't figure out an answer even after extensive Googling.

**What MaterialUI reccomends**

Import components one by one, when you need them, in such a manner:

```
import Box from '@material-ui/core'
import Button from '@material-ui/core'
import Whatever from '@material-ui/core'
```

**What I want to do (pseudocode, not real ES6):**

`import {Box, Button, Whatever} under namespace MaterialUI from '@material-ui/core'`

**so that I can use something like**

```
<MaterialUI.Box>
<MaterialUI.Button> ...
<MaterialUI.Whatever> ...
```

That seems to be available only if one imports the whole library in this manner:

`import * as MaterialUI from '@material-ui/core'`

which is explicitly noted as bad practice.

**I suppose I could use something like**

```
import Box as MaterialUI_Box from '@material-ui/core'
import Button as MaterialUI_Button from '@material-ui/core'
import Whatever as MaterialUI_Whatever from '@material-ui/core'
```

but this feels like reinventing namespaces manually and involves a lot of repetition.

**So, how do I NOT import the whole library but still get the benefits of namespace for the components that I actually choose to import?**

I hope I've been clear and that my question has value for others who might be sharing my uncertainty.
Thanks :-)

Comment: If you use destructuring, only the item imported will be bundled. `import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';` or `import Button from '@material-ui-/core/Button'`

Comment: Does this enable me to import multiple components under the same namespace, in such a way (pseudocode): `import {A, B, C} as SomeNamespace from 'libraryXYZ'` so that I can use `<SomeNamespace.A>` ? That's the question basically.

Comment: You can import Button as Whateveryouwant, but will NOT have whatever.Button. I see it unnecessary, can you pls explain why you want that?

Comment: Always you can import all your desired components from material in another file, and export default an object with those keys in it and use it like you want.

Comment: Well, the question explains it very clearly in my opinion.

Comment: I think I could use what you've just suggested, can you provide a link where I can find more details please?

Answer (score 3):

Centralize your imports from material in your own file, and then use it to import those in your views. It could be something like this

```
// File: myMaterial.js
import { Button, Card } from '@material-ui/core';

export default {
  Button,
  Card
}
```

Now in your view:

```
import MyMaterial from '../myMaterial';
```

Use it:

```
<MyMaterial.Button />
<MyMaterial.Card />
```